# R ggplot - Plot a line over a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I need to add a trend line to the bar plot I have built with ggplot. The line should give me the total qty of service for each calendar week.

This is my code:

```
sample <- data.frame(service_type = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                     qty = c(38,185,87,29,12,133,2,14,31,2,9,59,60,43,137,135,31,159,15,32,1),
                     year_week = c("2022 - CW02","2022 - CW02","2022 - CW02","2022 - CW03","2022 - CW03","2022 - CW03","2022 - CW04","2022 - CW04","2022 - CW04","2022 - CW05","2022 - CW05","2022 - CW05","2022 - CW06","2022 - CW06","2022 - CW06","2022 - CW07","2022 - CW07","2022 - CW07","2022 - CW08","2022 - CW08","2022 - CW08"),
                     xlabel2 = c("Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Jan-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22","Feb-22")
)

sample <- sample %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(year_week, 1), "%Y - CW%U%u")) 

sample %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = date, fill = service_type, weight = qty) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(y= qty, group = interaction(service_type,date))) +
  #geom_text(aes(y = qty + 2*sign(qty), label=qty), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size = 2.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(A = "#FFC000",
               B = "#92D050",
               C = "#AE5AFF")
  )+
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%Y - CW%U",
    date_breaks = "1 week",
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = as.Date(paste0("15-", unique(sample$xlabel2)), "%d-%b-%y"),
      labels = \(x) format(x, "%b-%y")
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "left", axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),axis.title = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())
```

I receive this message and I don't understand why:

> 'geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?'

Comment: Try `geom_line(aes(y= qty, group = service_type))` to get a line for each service_type.

Answer (score 0):

View() your data, there is literaly only 1 data point for each interaction of service_type and date.
Drop interaction and just go with service_type and you will get what you want.
Also, depending on the preference,
`geom_smooth(aes(y= qty, group = service_type), se =F)`
might be better than geom line, but that's just completely up to you.

Comment: Hi, what I need is the total qty per calendar week. If I group only for service_type I will have three different lines.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, for your `geom_line` layer, you want to sum *across* the service types & maintain only *one* group across all calendar weeks. `interaction()` achieves the exact opposite of that.

See if the following works for you?

```
ggplot(sample ) +

  # replace 'weight = qty' with 'y = qty', which is more straightforward
  aes(x = date, y = qty, fill = service_type) +

  # geom_col() is equivalent to geom_bar(stat = "identity") and understands
  # y for aesthetic mapping
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +

  # set a single group for geom_line() and sum all the y values at each x value
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), stat = "summary", fun = sum) +

  # adjust dodge position for geom_text() to match date axis
  geom_text(aes(label=qty), 
            position=position_dodge(7 * 0.9), vjust = 0)+

# no major changes below; reduced indents to conserve space for easier reading
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "#FFC000", B = "#92D050", C = "#AE5AFF"))+
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%Y - CW%U",
    date_breaks = "1 week",
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = as.Date(paste0("15-", unique(sample$xlabel2)), "%d-%b-%y"),
      labels = \(x) format(x, "%b-%y")
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "left",
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
# (I hid the minor grid as it serves no purpose for the date axis & is 
#  somewhat distracting)
```

[image: result]